# Modify specific cell in uicollectionview

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When adding cells to my UICollectionView using the cellForItemAtIndexPath I'm trying to target the first cell and add a coloured overlay to the image in the cell. However, the code seems to target multiple cells as they are created (though not all) even though it doesn't seem to be called a corresponding number of times (It may apply the overlay to 3 or 4 cells but only call it twice [the second time is when reloadData() is called]). How do I apply the colour overlay to the first and only to the first cell?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell

    if(self.userList.count > 0) {
        cell.frame.size = CGSize(width: 202, height: 207)
        if(indexPath.item < self.userList.count) {
            cell.myImage.image = self.userList[indexPath.item].image
            cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myImage.frame.size.width / 2
            cell.myImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
            if(indexPath.item == 0) {
                print("Overlay")
                let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: cell.frame.width / 2, y: cell.frame.height / 2), radius: CGFloat((cell.myImage?.frame.size.width)! / 2), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
                let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
                shapeLayer.fillColor = self.overlayColor.CGColor

                cell.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            }
         }
     }
     return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no problem if you use `item` or `row` you have to put else and remove `CAShapeLayer` otherwise it will show in the other cell item because the cell will be reuse. replace your code with below.

```
if(indexPath.item == 0) {   // if(indexPath.row == 0) {
   let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: cell.frame.width / 2, y: cell.frame.height / 2), radius: CGFloat((cell.myImage?.frame.size.width)! / 2), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
   let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
   shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
   shapeLayer.fillColor = self.overlayColor.CGColor

   cell.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
} else {
   let sublayers = cell.layer.sublayers
   for sublayer in sublayers! {
        if sublayer.isKindOfClass(CAShapeLayer) {
            sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it and helped me sort out a few other issues that I had that I figured were linked.